# Cookie for three text boxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have 3 text boxes in my page. I want to retain the previous values after refresh. I have the following. The problem is that even if I enter three different values, all the text boxes are having the same value(**of the first one**) after refresh. Where am I going wrong?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".companyname").val($.cookie("companyname")||'');
      $(".companyname1").val($.cookie("companyname1")||'');
      $(".companyname2").val($.cookie("companyname2")||'');
      $('#submit').click(function(){
          var value = $('.companyname').val();
          $.cookie('companyname', value);
          var value1 = $('.companyname1').val();
          $.cookie('companyname1', value);
          var value2 = $('.companyname2').val();
          $.cookie('companyname2', value);
          window.location.reload();
      });
 });
```

These are my elements

```
  <input type="text" name = "companyname" class = "companyname"> <br/>
  <input type="text" name = "companyname1" class = "companyname1"> <br/>
  <input type="text" name = "companyname2" class = "companyname2"> <br/>
  <input type="Submit" value = " Submit " id="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Overlooked the line

```
 $.cookie('companyname', value);
```

Here is the corrected code:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".companyname").val($.cookie("companyname")||'');
      $(".companyname1").val($.cookie("companyname1")||'');
      $(".companyname2").val($.cookie("companyname2")||'');
      $('#submit').click(function(){
          var value = $('.companyname').val();
          $.cookie('companyname', value);
          var value1 = $('.companyname1').val();
          $.cookie('companyname1', value1);
          var value2 = $('.companyname2').val();
          $.cookie('companyname2', value2);
          window.location.reload();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Edit your original post rather than posting an answer.

Comment: But that code looks identical to the "broken" code in the question?